# Extend photo-diode detector to support multiple sensors

Tags: c++, struct, arduino, embedded

I am quite new to C++, so I was hoping someone can help me answer my question. I am building an embedded system using Arduino.

I have a number of photo-diodes that generate an event when an physical object passes the sensor. The object passes the sensor too quickly, so the signal is short-lived and on non deterministic length.  So I wish to implement a timer that holds the state to a period following detection.

The following code is my attempt to implement this for a single photo-diode sensor, (**Note:** I have not tried to compile it yet, there might be some mistakes). However how can I extend this to support multiple sensors.

Here is code:

```
struct DiodeResult {
  bool diodePassed;
  unsigned long timeOfSet;
}


void loop() {
  static DiodeResult diodeResult;

  bool diodePassed = readDiode();
  if (diodePassed) {
    diodeResult.diodePassed = true;
    diodeResult.timeOfSet = millis();
  } else {
    if ((millis() - diodeResult.timeOfSet) > (5*1000) {
      diodeResult.diodePassed = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"do I need to copy this struct 10x times"*. if you mean create `struct DiodeResult0`, `struct DiodeResult9;`, no. If you want to have 10 instances, then `std::array<DiodeResult, 10>` seems fine.

Comment: Looks like an X-Y problem - you are asking about a _solution_ that may not be appropriate and which you do not know how to implement.  Better to ask a question about the _problem_ - i.e. _"time that diode is outputting 1 is too short"_ - you may get a better solution that way.  For example why not have a _static object_ in the same way you have a _static struct instance_?  A `class` and a `struct` in C++ are in fact the same thing only with different default visibility and inheritance.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Either your MCU can register the diode change, or it cannot. Variables don't "drop back to 0" by themselves, unless you mean the hardware register. The solution then is to read it and store it in a separate variable. Interrupts may or may not be relevant.

Comment: Explain what the code is required to do rather then asking the much narrower question about structures.  It seems that on some short  event triggered by a photo-diode, you want a Boolean to become true for 5 seconds, and that you have 10 instances of these monostable pulses?  If that is the case, ask that. We could answer that, but not as an answer to the question as it stands.

Comment: Apart from that you should test your code before asking a question about it - what if it just works and does exactly what you need?  Then you are just wasting our time.

Comment: @Clifford "It seems that on some short event triggered by a photo-diode, you want a Boolean to become true for 5 seconds, and that you have 10 instances of these monostable pulses?".. Yes, thats exactly what I am looking for. I thought this struct takes care of it - I break the problem into smaller steps and I thought this variable ,,lifetime,, is dealt via this struct, but if you think its not way to go, I will gladly learn.

Comment: @Lundin I am confused, you say it doesnt make any sense and then you proceed to describe exactly what I meant. Indeed I mean variable that is changed by the sensor output. If the sensor is not detecting anything, the variable drops back to 0 immediatly. I was looking for way to delay this variable reset AND a way to do it for multiple sensors without writing it multiple times. //edit: I was actually looking only for way to do it multiple times, because I thought the struct takes care of the first part

Comment: @GIA_96 : I think the problem is the phrase _" object that is being registered by the diode, quickly moves away_".  It suggests an object being instantiated then destroyed or going out of scope, but it seems that in fact you are referring to the state of tge diode output being transient.  In your previous comment you also referred to "_variable lifetime_" which has very specific meaning that does not match your usage.  You are referring to the duration of the variable state, not the lifetime of the variable.  I have posted an answer with that interpretation.

Comment: @Clifford "It suggests an object being instantiated then destroyed or going out of scope, but it seems that in fact you are referring to the state of the diode output being transient." There seems to be collision of names, by my mistake. By object, I meant physical object, that is passing next to the photodiode. I think you realized it, just wanted to clarify it here.

Comment: @GIA_96 : Ah - that makes sense.

Comment: @GIA_96 :  I have heavily edited your question and title (which made little sense).  Hopefully I have not mutilated beyond what you really wanted to know.  If I have do roll it back, but I think it will then need work if you are to save it from closure and/or further down-votes.

Comment: @Clifford Unless, someone says that computer code is also physical. Some philosopher might wander into these waters.

Comment: @Clifford Huge part of learning is to learn the right language. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing solution can be extended to handle multiple photo-diodes simply by using an array of `DiodeResult` instances:

```
void loop()
{
    static DiodeResult diodeResult[DIODE_COUNT];

    for( int i = 0; i < DIODE_COUNT; i++ )
    {
        bool diodePassed = readDiode( i ) ;

        if( diodePassed )
        {
            diodeResult[i].diodePassed = true;
            diodeResult[i].timeOfSet = millis();
        }
        else
        {
            if( (millis() - diodeResult[i].timeOfSet) > (5 * 1000)
            {
                diodeResult[i].diodePassed = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or perhaps more "Arduino-like":

```
void loop()
{
    static DiodeResult diodeResult[DIODE_COUNT];
    static int i= 0 ;

    bool diodePassed = readDiode( i ) ;

    if( diodePassed )
    {
        diodeResult[i].diodePassed = true;
        diodeResult[i].timeOfSet = millis();
    }
    else
    {
        if( (millis() - diodeResult[i].timeOfSet) > (5 * 1000)
        {
            diodeResult[i].diodePassed = false;
        }
    }

    // Next diode on next loop iteration
    i = (i + 1) % DIODE_COUNT ; 
}
```

However it relies on the photo-diode state remaining active for at least as long as it takes to iterate all ten sensors.  This may be the case, but it highly dependent on your application and possibly the implementation of `readDiode()`.  It may be necessary if polling is not fast enough to use interrupts.

Moreover the solution could arguably be improved by a little OOP:

```
class cMonoStable
{
    public : 
        cMonoStable( unsigned long period_ms ) : m_time_ms(time_ms)
        {
        }

        void trigger()
        {
            m_start_ms = millis() ;
        }

        bool getState()
        {
            return m_start_ms - millis() < m_time_ms ;
        }

    private :
        unsigned long m_time_ms;
        unsigned long m_start_ms
};

class cPhotoDiodeTriggeredMonostable : public cMonoStable
{
    public :
        cPhotoDiodeTriggeredMonostable( unsigned long period_ms, int diode = 0 ) : cMonoStable( period_ms ) : m_diode(diode)
        {
        }

        void update()
        {
            if( readDiode( m_diode ) )
            { 
                trigger() ;
            }
        }

    private:
        int m_diode ;
} ;

static const int DIODE_COUNT = 10 ;
static cPhotoDiodeTriggeredMonostable* photo_diode_state[DIODE_COUNT];

void setup()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < DIODE_COUNT; i++ )
    {
        photo_diode_state[i] = new cPhotoDiodeTriggeredMonostable( 5000, i ) ;
    }
}

void loop()
{
    static int i = 0 ;
    photo_diode_state[i]->update() ;

    if( photo_diode_state[i].getState() )
    {
        // do whatever - state remains true for 5 seconds after diode was last active.
    }
}
```

It looks a little long winded, but not how simple the individual elements are, and the `cMonoStable` class can be applied to other sensor types with similar characteristics, just be implementing a super-class with a different `update()` implementation.

Comment: @GIA_96 : Ok , note that the core of the code in the first two solutions is essentially yours - I have not tested it  either.  If that part does not work, don't blame me - it is out-of-scope in the narrow context of your question.  It seems plausible at least.